# How to access jenkins pipeline stage variable for concated sh command

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

#### i define a variable current_tag at stage tagging

[image]

#### use variable current_tag for folder name,and create it

[image]

#### check variable's value is exist

[image]

#### result

[image]

#### copy something into folder

[image]

#### but,execute two command ,not only 1

/usr/bin/cp -f auth/target/auth-1.0.jar /data/bin/packet-net-backend/bf_prod/20200824143201-v1.0.0.138

#### and

/backend
[image]

#### another way

[image]

#### current_tag's value is gone

[image]

what is the correct way

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd shell command is not executed correctly because groovy use double quotes `"` for variable interpolation. See https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation

Try to wrap the shell command with double quotes only. You can escape quotes inside command if needed.

Right: `sh label: "my-command" script: "ping ${host}"`

Wrong: `sh label: "my-command" script: 'ping ${host}'`